# How to set the color palette in the .Rprofile

Tags: r, colors, palette, color-palette, rprofile

I'd like to change the Color palette on startup of R. Thus I copied the following source-code to my `.Rprofile`

```
palette(c(
  "#2e3436"   # (Aluminium 6)
  , "#ef2929" # (Scarlet Red 1)
  , "#73d216" # (Chameleon 2)
  , "#3465a4" # (Sky Blue 2)
  , "#fcaf3e" # (Orange 1)
  , "#ad7fa8" # (Plum 1)
  , "#babdb6" # (Butter 1)
  , "#babdb6" # (Aluminium 3)
))
```

On startup of R the following message shows up:

> Error: Could not fine the function 'palette'

Is it not possible to change the palette on startup?

Comment: Maybe add `library(grDevices)` before that?

Comment: That opens an annoying window on startup. Which packages are loaded after the .Rprofile, and where is it defined? (I never had to load `grDevices` before calling `palette()` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?Startup`

> Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced only
>     the 'base' package is loaded, so objects in other packages need to
>     be referred to by e.g. 'utils::dump.frames' or after explicitly
>     loading the package concerned.

So instead of `palette()`, call `grDevices::palette()`. (The call to `dev.off()` is  needed to eliminate the empty graphics window that is otherwise present following startup.)

```
grDevices::palette(c(
  "#2e3436"   # (Aluminium 6)
  , "#ef2929" # (Scarlet Red 1)
  , "#73d216" # (Chameleon 2)
  , "#3465a4" # (Sky Blue 2)
  , "#fcaf3e" # (Orange 1)
  , "#ad7fa8" # (Plum 1)
  , "#babdb6" # (Butter 1)
  , "#babdb6" # (Aluminium 3)
))

grDevices::dev.off()
```